# Formula condition with date

Tags: formula-field, date

I have this formula type field, the condition is correct but the problem I have is that when it is 02/29 as the end date, my field gives me an error, is that because I I used yers -1 maybe, if not, do you have any ideas to solve the problem?

```
IF(
AND(
TODAY() >DATE(
YEAR(EndDate__c)-1,
MONTH(EndDate__c),
DAY(EndDate__c)
) ,
TODAY() < EndDate__c
),true,false)
```

==> The all original formula

```
IF( AND (TODAY() > Start_Date__c ,TODAY() < DATE(YEAR(EndDate__c)-1,MONTH(EndDate__c),DAY(EndDate__c))),
IMAGE($Setup.CORE_Static_Resource_URL__c.CORE_Relative_URL_Path__c &"/image/Green.png","Green",16,16),
IF(
AND(
TODAY() >DATE(
YEAR(EndDate__c)-1,
MONTH(EndDate__c),
DAY(EndDate__c)
) ,
TODAY() < EndDate__c
),
IMAGE($Setup.CORE_Static_Resource_URL__c.CORE_Relative_URL_Path__c &"/image/Orange.png","Orange",16,16 ),IMAGE($Setup.CORE_Static_Resource_URL__c.CORE_Relative_URL_Path__c &"/image/Red.png","Red",16,16 )))
```

==> What I added based on your explication . Is it correct like this , or not :

```
IF( 
   AND (
   TODAY() > Start_Date__c ,
   
   OR(
        AND(
            MONTH(EndDate__c) <= 2,
            OR(
                AND(
                    MOD(YEAR(EndDate__c), 100) = 1,
                    MOD(YEAR(EndDate__c), 400) = 1
                ),
                AND(
                    MOD(YEAR(EndDate__c), 100) != 1,
                    MOD(YEAR(EndDate__c), 4) = 1
                )
            )
        ),
        AND(
            MONTH(EndDate__c) >= 3,
            OR(
                AND(
                    MOD(YEAR(EndDate__c), 100) = 0,
                    MOD(YEAR(EndDate__c), 400) = 0
                ),
                AND(
                    MOD(YEAR(EndDate__c), 100) != 0,
                    MOD(YEAR(EndDate__c), 4) = 0
                )
            )
    ),
    366,
    365
)

   )
   ),
IMAGE($Setup.CORE_Static_Resource_URL__c.CORE_Relative_URL_Path__c &"/image/Green.png","Green",16,16),
IF(
AND(
OR(
        AND(
            MONTH(EndDate__c) <= 2,
            OR(
                AND(
                    MOD(YEAR(EndDate__c), 100) = 1,
                    MOD(YEAR(EndDate__c), 400) = 1
                ),
                AND(
                    MOD(YEAR(EndDate__c), 100) != 1,
                    MOD(YEAR(EndDate__c), 4) = 1
                )
            )
        ),
        AND(
            MONTH(EndDate__c) >= 3,
            OR(
                AND(
                    MOD(YEAR(EndDate__c), 100) = 0,
                    MOD(YEAR(EndDate__c), 400) = 0
                ),
                AND(
                    MOD(YEAR(EndDate__c), 100) != 0,
                    MOD(YEAR(EndDate__c), 4) = 0
                )
            )
    ),
    366,
    365
) ,
TODAY() < EndDate__c
),
IMAGE($Setup.CORE_Static_Resource_URL__c.CORE_Relative_URL_Path__c &"/image/Orange.png","Orange",16,16 ),
IMAGE($Setup.CORE_Static_Resource_URL__c.CORE_Relative_URL_Path__c &"/image/Red.png","Red",16,16 )))
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Thank you for posting your formula. But please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/374153/edit) your question to also include the *exact* copied/pasted error text. (And if you format your error text by putting it after a ">" in the SFSE editor, it will format it as a block quote and make it stand out as actual error text.)

Answer (score 0):

February only has 29 days on leap years (2016, 2020, 2024, 2028, etc...), so it's no wonder that `DATE(notALeapYear, 2, 29)` doesn't work. That one particular day is an *edge case*.

The [Formula Operators and Functions documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions.htm&type=5) also says this very clearly

> Returns a date value from year, month, and day values you enter. Salesforce displays an error on the detail page if the value of the DATE function in a formula field is an invalid date, such as February 29 in a non-leap year.

There are several ways you could work around that:

- Using a validation rule to prevent `End_Date__c` from being a February 29th
- Detect if `End_Date__c` is a February 29th, and then subtract 1 from the result of `DATE(stuff)` if it is
- Use date subtraction, instead of date comparison, to sidestep the issue

The date subtraction approach in a nutshell, would be

- Take `End_Date__c`, and subtract `TODAY()` from it
- Check to see if that result is less than 365
- And also check that `TODAY()` is less than `End_Date__c`

Of course that just swaps one edge case for another (or rather, it reveals *another* edge case that you weren't considering). If your end date is between February 29th of a leap year and March 1st of the following year, you'd want to see if the date difference is 366 instead.

You *could* handle that additional consideration, but you'll have to decide for yourself if it's worth the effort. Date handling in formulas gets out of hand *very quickly*. A quick shot at the 365/366 determination is

```
IF(
    OR(
        AND(
            MONTH(End_Date__c) <= 2,
            OR(
                AND(
                    MOD(YEAR(End_Date__c), 100) = 1,
                    MOD(YEAR(End_Date__c), 400) = 1
                ),
                AND(
                    MOD(YEAR(End_Date__c), 100) != 1,
                    MOD(YEAR(End_Date__c), 4) = 1
                )
            )
        ),
        AND(
            MONTH(End_Date__c) >= 3,
            OR(
                AND(
                    MOD(YEAR(End_Date__c), 100) = 0,
                    MOD(YEAR(End_Date__c), 400) = 0
                ),
                AND(
                    MOD(YEAR(End_Date__c), 100) != 0,
                    MOD(YEAR(End_Date__c), 4) = 0
                )
            )
    ),
    366,
    365
)
```

#### A few other notes

- You'll still want to check to make sure if TODAY() is < End_Date__c
- The current `IF()` you have surrounding the entirety of the rest of the formula is useless and should be removed.

  - `IF(<condition>, true, false)` can *always* be simplified to `<condition>`
  - `IF(<condition>, false, true)` can *always* be simplified to `NOT(<condition>)`
  - This concept also applies to Apex
    `if(<condition> == true)` => `if(<condition>)`,
    `if(<condition> == false)` => `if(!<condition>)`

Comment: I added the new version of the code basing on the explanation and the code you shared with me , code you please check it